# Python: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: python, powershell

I'm using subprocess to change (cd) directory to the one specified but I get

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '\Themes'.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd $(spicetify -c | Split-Path)\Themes
```

I'm using this on a Windows machine to change directory to that particular folder (created by Spicetify CLI). It works on Powerhsell but not on my Python script:

```
import subprocess

def main():
    call(["powershell", "cd", "$(spicetify -c | Split-Path)\Themes"])
def call(commands):
    subprocess.call(commands, shell=True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I think this is a  quoting issue. You will need a pair of surrounding double quotes to pass to PowerShell. Maybe using outer single quotes will work: Maybe something like `call(["powershell", "cd", '"$(spicetify -c | Split-Path)\Themes"'])` will work.

Comment: I tried it and got this error now:
```
PS D:\Documents\Code> python theme.py
'Split-Path)\Themes\""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: I guess you could surround the entire argument in the subexpression operator: `call(["powershell", "cd", "$((spicetify -c | Split-Path)+'\Themes')"])`

Comment: After some further testing with the CMD shell, I had to escape a number of things. I don't know what your shell is of course. We do need to escape inner quotes and the special `|` (special in CMD).  I had to escape the path backslashes as well, but I will leave those out since it seems you don't have to: `call(["powershell", "cd", "\"$(spicetify -c ^| Split-Path)\Themes\""])`. Or `call(["powershell", "cd", '"$(spicetify -c ^| Split-Path)\Themes"'])`.Your solution probably won't be exactly like this but I think a similar approach will need to be used.

Comment: I tried what you said but it is not giving any error but also not changing the directory and staying in the same directory. I'm using powershell of Windows 10.

Comment: The thing is, I can type `cd "$(spicetify -c | Split-Path)\Themes"` in Powershell and it works, I have no idea why it wouldn't work in Python.

Comment: I think that is happening because the shell is exiting. You can try `call(["powershell", "-noexit", "cd", '"$(spicetify -c ^| Split-Path)\Themes"'])`

Comment: Okay, that did cd to that directory however any code after that line does not work. Not even a print statement which is not using call()